# What is the historical accuracy of the film Valkyrie?

Tags: propaganda

How historically accurate are films made about Nazi Germany? Since they are made after WW2, are they inherently biased towards the Allies?  Taking the movie [Valkyrie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0985699/?ref_=nv_sr_2) for example,  how historically accurate are these types of films.

Comment: I found the German films about the event very good. I do not know what's the quality of the American film.

Comment: A quick check on the IMDb Goofs page for the movie shows a number of anachronisms and other inaccuracies (the factual errors section is quite long). As this is a dramatisation rather than a documentary, some of these would have been deliberate choices by the writers and director for 'artistic effect'.

Comment: "History is written by the victors." . Avoid Hollywood movies for history lessons, instead use them as starting point for your own research .

Comment: @r.s.29 also worth adding that Hollywood films also are entertainment, which is a second black mark from a history perspective.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Valkyrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie_(film)#Historical_accuracy) has a fairly lengthy section on this. Doesn't this answer your main question? If not, please edit to let us know what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible for you to concentrate your question on a particular event? Enumerating every single anachronism in this movie will be tedious. And we certainly can't evaluate *all* of the movies about Nazi Germany from "Inglourious Busterds" to "Das Boot".